# Magento Widget in Product Catalog

Tags: magento

I have created a Widget, which inserts a form, with a WYSIWYG editor.

But the WYSIWYG editor in the Catalog Section, doesn't provide the Widget button on its editor.

I tried pasting the widget code `{{widget type="module/widget_name"}}`, into the description area, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a short tut, on how to enable the mentioned feature:

[Magento : Enable Widget/Block Codes in Catalog Product](http://jmpmaniacs.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/magento-enable-widgetblock-codes-in-catalog-product/)